# How to use regex to uppercase and to remove all alphanumerics EXCEPT for Pipe symbol

Tags: python, regex

In Python 3.7.3, I have:

```
def testscrub(x):    
    x = ' '.join(re.split(r'\W+', x.upper()))
    return x


teststring = 'abc$ABC|xyz*XYZ|123#321|888'
teststring_wanted = 'ABC ABC|XYZ XYZ|123 321|888'


answer = testscrub(teststring)

print('teststring=',teststring)
print('answer=',answer)
print('teststring_wanted=',teststring_wanted)
```

...emits as output:

```
teststring= abc$ABC|xyz*XYZ|123#321|888
answer= ABC ABC XYZ XYZ 123 321 888
teststring_wanted= ABC ABC|XYZ XYZ|123 321|888
```

I have tried numerous ways to escape the | symbol, but to no avail.  Can anyone help?  Thanks.

Comment: "I have tried numerous ways to escape the | symbol" what ways did you try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```py
def testscrub(x):    
    return ' '.join(re.split(r'[^\w|]+', x.upper()))
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/BsMQv5/2).

**EXPLANATION**

```py
  [^\w|]+                  any character except: word characters (a-
                           z, A-Z, 0-9, _), '|' (1 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
```

**[Python code](https://tio.run/##RU7NCsIwGLv3KQoKbXUMtl2GsIP6Ev7DNqtWtCvfvrFO@u51P4flkOSQhJgOX5VOvFdfUwFSkOQuHxRljXUJTcGt2NAeZCBLM8ooC9@V0hxkWJuPQg7sfLu07rpmAbVhY4wELoQYGyCxAU0tIeMigtLPYSQvyuV2t3e2@60Ox5OL4mSRxJFL05SRXNethD42v5jbgphekLMplbFgMsL7Pw)**:

```py
import re
def testscrub(x):    
    x = ' '.join(re.split(r'[^\w|]+', x.upper()))
    return x

teststring = 'abc$ABC|xyz*XYZ|123#321|888'
answer = testscrub(teststring)
print('answer=',answer)
```

**Results**: `answer= ABC ABC|XYZ XYZ|123 321|888`